# Sending data with form and reading it from Request.Form

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I have form like below in `mvc` view:

```
<form name="aspnetForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="ORDER_ID" name="ORDER_ID">
    <input type="hidden" id="STATUS" name="STATUS" value="SHOW">
</form>
```

I want to send it from js with below:

```
function send(orderKeyId, sUrl) {
    document.aspnetForm.ORDER_ID.value = encodeURIComponent(orderKeyId);
    document.aspnetForm.action = sUrl;
    document.aspnetForm.submit();
}
```

Everything works, but I have to read it in `aspx.cs` from `Request.QueryString`, but I need to use `Request.Form` because of I need clear url without any queryString inside. I mean, it automatically add ORDER_ID to queryString instead of sending it in form.

Comment: According to w3c the default method for form submit is get, which sends parameters in query string. If you want to have a clear url, perhaps you should use post. That should also allow you to get the values from request.form

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing quote in `Request.Form["ORDER_ID]`

Comment: Thanks, this is only my mistyping. Already corrected in main post.